# Scala finds my implicit conversion twice, causing "ambiguous implicit" errors

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I'm playing around with a third party library that has a `PropertyContainer` interface. It lets you get/set properties in terms of `java.lang.Object`, but it really only supports java primitives, strings, and arrays of those things. So I'm trying to make a light wrapper over the property container class.

**Property.scala**

```
class Property[A <% NeoTypeEvidence[A]](val name: String) {
  def apply(pc: PropertyContainer) = pc.getProperty(name).asInstanceOf[A]
  def update(pc: PropertyContainer, value: A) = pc.setProperty(name, value)
}
```

**package.scala**

```
{
  sealed trait NeoTypeEvidence[A]
  object AnyValTypeEvidence extends NeoTypeEvidence[AnyVal]
  object StringTypeEvidence extends NeoTypeEvidence[String]
  object AnyValArrayTypeEvidence extends NeoTypeEvidence[Array[AnyVal]]
  object StringArrayTypeEvidence extends NeoTypeEvidence[Array[String]]

  implicit def anyValToEvidence(v: AnyVal) = AnyValTypeEvidence
  implicit def stringToEvidence(s: String) = StringTypeEvidence
  implicit def anyValArrayToEvidence(v: Array[AnyVal]) = AnyValArrayTypeEvidence
  implicit def stringArrayToEvidence(s: Array[String]) = StringArrayTypeEvidence
}
```

**test file**

```
val name = new Property[String]("name")
```

I would expect that to work just fine, assuming that the compiler finds the implicit StringTypeEvidence to satisfy the condition of `[String <% NeoTypeEvidence[String]]`. What I get instead is an error:

```
ambiguous implicit values:  
both method stringToEvidence in package neo of type 
  (s: String) com.dylemma.neo.package.StringTypeEvidence.type  
 and method stringToEvidence in package neo of type 
  (s: String) com.dylemma.neo.package.StringTypeEvidence.type  
match expected type 
String => com.dylemma.neo.package.NeoTypeEvidence[String]
```

So scala is finding my implicit conversion twice?? I've done a clean+rebuild several times but that hasn't fixed anything. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

*edit/note:* I notice that this only seems to happen when I try to create a `Property` in the same package as where the implicits were defined. So if I do the exact same code in `some.other.package` and have an import for `the.main.package._`, it works without complaint. I still don't understand why, though.

Comment: Works for me, but nevertheless you could move the implicits to `NeoTypeEvidence`'s companion object and see if that helps.

Comment: Is the thing in `package.scala` inside a package object that you forgot to mention?

Comment: Yes the trait and implicits were inside `package object neo`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are importing the implicit twice. Check the [rules for implicit resolution here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html#where-do-implicits-come-from).

Most likely (albeit hard to say with your sample), you are using an explicit import while also working on the same package, where the implicit is already present by default.